# bootstrap grid with 24 cols and 12 cols on the same page

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a question about bootstrap's grid system.
I need in the same page 2 grids - row with 12 cols and row with 24 cols.

In row with 24 cols i have 3 elements - with 1 cols, with 20 cols and with 3 cols.
I can not split 2th element (with 20/24) as Gleb Kemarsky mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38384830/4527967)

I need in the same page grid with normal (12 cols), so i can not use bootstrap's @grid-columns 's variable. As zessx mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26679237/4527967)

Comment: Why setting `$grid-columns: 24` is not an option? With that you could use `.col-2` as a column in your 12 column grid (2 * 12 = 24).

Comment: This could resolve my problem. But is there other way to do it?

Comment: In case the 12 column grid fits the rest of your entire site, then you could create some custom classes for the alternative grid e.g.: `.24col-1`, `.24col-20` and `.24col-3`, and you could use these in the "extra" situation.